# Configuring IntelliJ so it takes a specific configuration file to run tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, functional-testing

I am using Play Framework 2.3 and IntelliJ IDEA 14. I use a Mailer plugin in my application. I wrote a few functional tests that work perfectly when I run the `test` command in the SBT console, after adding this line to **build.sbt**:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

And this one to the file **conf/application.test.conf**:

```
smtp.mock=yes
```

Unfortunately, when I run tests directly from IntelliJ, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: smtp.host needs to be set in application.conf in order to use this plugin (or set smtp.mock to true)
```

I tried launching those tests with the VM argument `-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf`, without success.

Here are two examples of the tests I am trying to execute:

```
@Test
public void testWithServer() {
    running(testServer(3333), () -> {
        assertThat(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get().get(1000).getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
    });
}

@Test
public void testWithBrowser() {
    running(testServer(3333), HTMLUNIT, browser -> {
        browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
        assertThat(browser.$("title").getText()).isEqualTo("Welcome");
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, the `config.file` setting, and thus the `conf/application.test.conf` file, is used by SBT. As such, IntelliJ IDEA when running the test does not load it and its contained settings even when you specify the `config.file` setting via the VM Options text field. Instead, you must put the `-Dsmtp.mock=yes` setting (any any other settings that are in the `application.test.conf` file) in the VM Options text field.

If that works, you can add the argument(s) to the VM Options text field to the JUnit settings under the Default group in the Run/Debug Configuration dialog so any new tests you create will have it preset.

Comment: I was hoping that something could make IntelliJ take any config file, but this works so thanks a lot. And you're right, this file is used by SBT.

Comment: You should [open a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) asking that test & application run/debug configurations be able to take a configuration file for setting VM options. I think that would be a great enhancement. Post the request's ID/link here and I'd certainly vote for it. Others would likely as well.

Comment: You could also add the option -Dconfig.file directly into VM options, that's what I do and it works well, just be sure to set the absolute path, relative doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

In your run configurations, select JUnit, and then click the wrench to edit the default config. Then, in VM options, add `-Dconfig.file=/absolute/path/to/application.test.conf`.